# True, **and** false

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Put a bit of money
On the center of your eye.
(As some folks are known to do
For others, when they die.)
Now make sure you take the turn
That you should always take,
And if you can get nothing right,
Your answer's a mistake!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a bit of money

> Put a bit of 'mon**e**y' = e

On the center of your eye

> On the center of 'you**r** eye' = r

Now make sure that you take the turn that you should always take

> right turn = r

And if you get nothing right

> o + r = or

Your answer's a mistake!

> error

The title: True and false

> Error is the true (correct) answer and it also means incorrect.

Comment: Correct! Well done, sir!